# Get process number of Java application

Tags: java, bash

I have the following script:

```
java -cp "some-classpath" my.package.MyClass
echo $1 > "$java_file"
```

The Java process starts a server.

I would like to get the process ID of the Java command and to write it to the file `$java_file`. Then, using that, I will kill the server.

However, nothing is written in the file.

How can I get the process ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
java -cp "some-classpath" my.package.MyClass &
echo $! > "$java_file"
```

Comment: The PID is written to file, so this works. However, I'm getting an error from the Java process `java.net.BindException: Address already in use`. This didn't appear before. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I do. I guess that you don't stop the process when exiting the application. Just `kill <pid>` before starting another instance. Make sure that you call `System.exit(0)` to stop the application. Not return from `main`